# F# add values to existing list

Tags: list, f#

Continuing with the series of creating card game with F#. Now I am stuck with adding values to list of cards. I have

```
type Player = {Name : String; Hand : Card list}
```

I am able to get the card from the deck and it works well. I can also create new list with

```
let player = {Name = "Player"; Hand = List.Empty}
let testlist = List.append player.Hand anotherlist
```

But I cannot figure out how to put add the anotherlist directly to players hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `with` construct:

```
let playerWithHand = { player with Hand = testlist }
```

As records in F# are immutable, you do not typically mutate an existing record (although there are ways to do that too) and instead, you create a new value representing the new state of the player. The `with` keyword makes this very easy, because it clones a record and changes some of its properties to new values as specified.

Comment: alright. thanks a lot! now I can get further with this.